# Quiero poder hacer que mi programa solo responda cuando desde la command line se le pase 2 argumentos (el 1ero el ejecutador y el 2do un int)

Tags: c

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

  if (argc == 2)
```

El problema es que no se como decirle al programa que solo opere cuando argv[1] sea un int, y en su defecto salga del programa.

Comment: ¿Has probado a emplear la función `isdigit` con el parámetro `argc`?

Comment: No, no lo he probado y tampoco sabría cómo (soy muy principiante). Porque ya he puesto int argc, y necesito que el 2do parametro sea un int, pero no me deja ponerle isdigit a argv[1] ya que resulta en segmentation fault. Me puedes explicar un poco como harías para ponerle isdigit a argc?

Comment: No lo indiques que es un número ya que lo que lees de la consola siempre será un string (o char)

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero es que lo que hay dentro de tu variable `argv[1]` nunca va a ser un `int` siempre va a ser tipo `char[]`. En el caso de que desde la consola se haya introducido un número el número estará así: `{'1','2','3'}` en este caso el 123.

Tienes que tener en cuenta que `'1'` no es un número es la letra que representa al 1.

Para poder transformar esa variable que es `char[]` a su correspondiente valor en `int` hay que usar la función `atoi()` que viene en la librería `stdlib.h` y esa misma función te dice si lo que hay dentro de tu variable `argv[1]` es un número.La función `atoi()` funciona así:

Dentro de los parentesis como argumento solo le tienes que pasar tu variable de tipo `char[]` (en este caso argv[1]) y te va a debolver un `int` que es el resultado de la conversión.Si por alguna razón en el `char[]` que le pasas hay letras como la `'a'` el `int` que debuleve es igual a 0.

Con esa funión puedes hacer tu programa siempre y cuando no esperes que desde la consola se pueda pasar el número 0.(En ese caso habría que hacerlo de una manera un poco más complicada)

Este es un ejemplo de como hacerlo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int aux=0;

    if (argc == 2)
    {
        aux=atoi(argv[1]);

        if (aux==0)
        {
            printf("Lo que has introducido no es un numero.");
            return 0; //Acaba el programa.
        }
    }

    //Aqui va tu programa

    printf("%d\n", aux); //imprime en consola el numero
    
    return 0;
}
```

Por último también decirte que si desde la consola entra en tu variable una cadena que empiece por un numero y siga con letras, la función `atoi` va a ignorar las letras.Por ejemplo:

`argv[1]` es igual a `"33abc"` `atoi` va a ignorar el `"abc"` y va a debolver 33.